# Shell script looking for a missing module

Tags: shell, cluster, module

I want to run a shell script on a compute cluster but I get an error because at some point it is looking for a module that does not exist since a major update on the cluster a few months ago. This module is not loaded in my script, therefore my script is not the  direct cause of the problem. One hypothesis is that the lmod cache is out of date, but I have no idea where is this cache. Or a file is sourced in which the module in question is loaded "intel/2018a".

Here is the complete message of the error:

```
> # User specific environment and startup programs

> PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
> + PATH=/node/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/cluster/bin:/cluster/home/sbarthelemy/.local/bin:/cluster/home/sbarthelemy/bin:/cluster/home/sbarthelemy/.local/bin:/cluster/home/sbarthelemy/bin

> export PATH
> + export PATH
> # NIRD settings 
> if [ `uname -n | head -3c` == 'tos' ]
> then
>  # intel compiler
>  source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/bin/compilervars.sh -arch intel64 -platform linux

>  # NCL 
>  export NCARG_ROOT=/opt/ncl64
>  export PATH=/opt/ncl64/bin/:${PATH}
> fi
> ++ uname -n
> ++ head -3c
> + '[' log == tos ']'

> module --force purge
> + module --force purge
> + '[' -z '' ']'
> + case "$-" in
> + __lmod_sh_dbg=vx
> + '[' -n vx ']'
> + set +vx
> Shell debugging temporarily silenced: export LMOD_SH_DBG_ON=1 for Lmod's output
> Shell debugging restarted
> + unset __lmod_sh_dbg
> + return 0
> module load StdEnv
> + module load StdEnv
> + '[' -z '' ']'
> + case "$-" in
> + __lmod_sh_dbg=vx
> + '[' -n vx ']'
> + set +vx
> Shell debugging temporarily silenced: export LMOD_SH_DBG_ON=1 for Lmod's output
> Shell debugging restarted
> + unset __lmod_sh_dbg
> + return 0
> module load intel/2018a
> + module load intel/2018a
> + '[' -z '' ']'
> + case "$-" in
> + __lmod_sh_dbg=vx
> + '[' -n vx ']'
> + set +vx
> Shell debugging temporarily silenced: export LMOD_SH_DBG_ON=1 for Lmod's output
Lmod has detected the following error:  The following module(s) are unknown: "intel/2018a"

> Please check the spelling or version number. Also try "module spider ..."
> It is also possible your cache file is out-of-date; it may help to try:
>   $ module --ignore_cache load "intel/2018a"
```

Comment: You should contact the admin(s) of the cluster to get them to tell you what the correct module name is. This is a local admin issue.